# Delay ajax from firing immediately (AJAX links api)

Tags: 7, ajax

**Problem**

I'm trying to add a bunch of CSS3 page transitions to my site. To do this, I'm loading the pages with AJAX using the [AJAX Links API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api), but I want to delay the AJAX call to allow for the animations.

However the ajax click handler seems to come straight from jquery.min.js, rather than module as I expected so I can't work out how to delay it. Does anyone know how to delay the ajax link click handler? (i.e. wrap it in a `setTimeout`.)

**Details**

I can prevent normal link clicks with:

```
  Drupal.behaviors.dsmooth_state = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('a.notajax').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();                   // prevent default anchor behavior
        var goTo = this.getAttribute("href"); // store anchor href

        // funky animations go here.

        setTimeout(function(){
             window.location = goTo;
        },800);       
      }); 
    }
  };
```

However the Drupal AJAX framework, uses a separate click handler for AJAX which is obviously not effected by this.

The AJAX Links API module defines the following click handler, however wrapping it in a setTimeout does nothing. I'm presuming that somehow this click handler sets the other one? I'm not really sure.

```
var ajaxLoading = false;
  Drupal.behaviors.ajaxLinksApi = {
    attach: function () {
      var trigger = Drupal.settings.ajax_links_api.trigger,
        negativeTrigger = Drupal.settings.ajax_links_api.negative_triggers;

      // match the elements from the positive selector
      var $elements = $(trigger);

      // remove elements if the negative trigger is specified
      if (negativeTrigger) {
        $elements = $elements.not(negativeTrigger);
      }

      // add the click handler
      $elements.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selector;
        if(!ajaxLoading) {
          ajaxLoading = true;
          var url = $(this).attr("href");
          var id = $(this).attr("rel");
          if(id) {
            selector = $(this).attr("rel");
          } else {
            selector = Drupal.settings.ajax_links_api.selector;
          }
          ajaxBefore(selector);
          ajaxLink(selector, url);          
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

//EDIT removed chrome information. I think I misunderstood what Chrome was putting out. It seems to list all event listeners as coming from jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was in fact a JS problem and not related to Drupal, I was in the correct place and writing some bad JS.

If you are trying to delay the AJAX clicks on the AJAX Links API module, you need to add a `setTimeout` and an extra variable to the JS defined in `ajax_links_api.js`

```
  $elements.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //This gets altered by setTimeout function, so save now.
    var store = this;
    var selector;
    setTimeout(function(e){
      if(!ajaxLoading) {
        ajaxLoading = true;
        var url = $(store).attr("href");
        var id = $(store).attr("rel");
        if(id) {
          selector = $(store).attr("rel");
        } else {
          selector = Drupal.settings.ajax_links_api.selector;
        }
        ajaxBefore(selector);
        ajaxLink(selector, url);
      }
    },800);  
  });
```